Read binary file with C# written by VB.NET FilePut
I have a VB Structure e.g. like this:
Structure MyTestStruct
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public stringfield As String
    <VBFixedString(40)> Public stringfield2 As String
    Public intfield As Integer
    Public doublefield As Double
    Public boolfield As Boolean
End Structure

I write many of the to a file with VB's FilePut.
How would I read this to a C# class (or struct)?
I tried with a C# class like:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class MyTestStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string stringfield;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
    public string stringfield2;
    public int intfield;
    public double doublefield;
    public bool boolfield;
}

and with FileStream.Read or also with a BinaryReader.
But it seems that I do not always get the correct number of records from my file. Also some umlauts in string values are not correctly encoded (running on Windows in Germany).
Has someone a good and safe method to do, what VB.NET does with FileGet in C#?
I also noticed, that there is Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet in C#. But it doesn't accept my variable to write the result to.
MyTestStruct data = new MyTestStruct();
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref data);

My expectation would be, to have a method in C#, give it a filename and the type to read to and read it's content to values of the given type. Just like VB.NET does with FileGet.
In VB it looks like:
Dim data As MyTestStruct
recLength = Len(data)
FileOpen(1, "data.dat", OpenMode.Random, , , recLength)

FilePut(1, data)

FileClose(1)

Dim datar As MyTestStruct
FileOpen(1, "data.dat", OpenMode.Random, , , recLength)
Do WHILE Not EOF(1)
    FileGet(1, datar)
Loop
FileClose(1)


I also noticed, that there is Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet in C# - yes, so you should use that. But it doesn't accept my variable - because it wants a struct, just like in VB. And you want to decorate that struct with the same Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBFixedStringAttribute, not with the marshaling attributes that are irrelevant.

Note that there is no harm in adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic (and Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core in .NET Core projects) in a C# project. They are just libraries like any other .NET library. However, prefer the standard library if possible, since the VB functions are often just wrappers around the standard library functions.

@GSerg OK, i changed my class to a struct, created a variable with the type of my struct and tried to call Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet. But VisualStudio says something like "converting to ref System.Array not possible"

Solved it for now in creating a VB project in my solution, put the VB.Structures into it as well as a method to reade it with VB and use that module from my c# project. Works like a charm.

You also should NOT be using FileGet or FilePut in the first place. They exist only for backwards compatibility when bringing forward old code.

Build the C# "class" as an actual structure, and with the actual VB attributes, like this:
// Depending on what version of VB you had, you may still need an attribute here
// But it would be a different attribute
public struct MyTestStruct
{
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBFixedStringAttribute(20)]
    public string stringfield;
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBFixedStringAttribute(40)]
    public string stringfield2;

    public int intfield;
    public double doublefield;
    public bool boolfield;
}

Then you can use the VB FileOpen() and FileGet() methods from C#
MyTestStruct data = new MyTestStruct();
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileOpen(1, "data.dat", OpenMode.Random, , , recLength)
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref data);

Note, though, that C# won't just let you keep those empty arguments for FileOpen(). You'll need to check the documentation for the defaults and actually fill in those places.

But you should not do this.
The old VB File I/O methods are deprecated and should not be used for new development. They exist only for porting forward code from very old VB systems, to buy you time to move the application to the newer file access APIs in System.IO or to modern serialization using something like JSON.

That doesn't work though, like noted by the OP. Despite a struct is a ValueType, it cannot be passed in place of a ref Valuetype. Amusingly, if you declare ValueType data = new MyTestStruct();, it compiles. You don't need to fill the missing arguments either, , RecordLength: recLength will suffice.

They exist only for porting forward code from very old VB systems And that is exactly why i am doing this.

Solved it for now in creating a VB project in my solution, put the VB.Structures into it as well as a method to reade it with VB and use that module from my c# project. Works like a charm.
